# Copy a file in container on docker run

Tags: docker, docker-run

I have a container, and i have a json file where is some information to start my api.
The problem is that i need to deploy **mutiple container with different json file**
So here is my question as we do the COPY in dockerfile is there a way to copy a file into the container on the **docker run**.

The use of secret is not possible because my client doesn't want to use swarm.

Thanks for reading

Comment: Have you tried mounting the file/folder with the file, as a volume in container?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the existing image as a base image, and add a new `Dockerfile` with the single `COPY` step. Then `docker build` would add the new file.

Alternatively -- and this is how secrets and configmaps are implemented anyway -- mount the file/folder with the `--mount` argument with `docker run`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

After you have your container running with docker run

Do a **docker ps** to get the docker **container id or name** and

```
docker cp local file containerid:/remote path
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/